# Why does an <area> element cause XSLT to drop the element contents and closing tag?

Tags: php, xslt

Running XSLTprocessor under PHP 5.2.11, I've run into an odd bug and have been able to replicate it with the [W3Schools XSLT demo](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) as well.

This is the streamlined case, which still produces the bug.
My goal is to take  hierarchically structured XML and "flatten" it to create a row structure.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<profiles>
<Subrecipient>
    <SubrecipientName>TESTING123</SubrecipientName>
    <Service>
        <ServiceName>BEFORE</ServiceName>
        <area>BETWEEN</area>
        <TypeDesc>AFTER</TypeDesc>
    </Service>
</Subrecipient>
</profiles>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<!--generally, don't output nodes that have no children -->
<xsl:template match="//*[not(*)]" />
<!-- except in "dataout" mode, namely when we're matching at a low level -->
<xsl:template match="//*[not(*)]" mode="dataout" >
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Service">
<row>
<!--next line selects all childless children of ancestors -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*/child::*[not(*)]" mode="dataout" />
<xsl:apply-templates  select="*[not(*)]" mode="dataout"  /> 
</row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output (spacing for clarity):

```
<row><subrecipientname>TESTING123</subrecipientname>
     <servicename>BEFORE</servicename>    
     <area>BETWEEN</area>
     <typedesc>AFTER</typedesc>
</row>
```

Actual output (for instance, from the W3Schools XSLT demo linked above):

```
<row><subrecipientname>TESTING123</subrecipientname>
      <servicename>BEFORE</servicename>
      <area>
      <typedesc>AFTER</typedesc>
</row>
```

I.e. the XSLT processes generates bad xml, omitting both the content and the closing tag for the "area" element. If I rename that element as "area_", all is well.

I don't know what XSLT processor W3Schools is using, so perhaps this is just a PHP XSLTprocessor bug, or there's something deep (and wonderful?) about XSLT and XPATH I don't understand.

I've got a workaround, but I'd prefer to understand what I've run into here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://w3fools.com/#why-it-matter

Comment: W3Schools is probably mistaking your XML `<area>` element for HTML's empty `<area>` element, and stripping away the content. I tried this with some other empty HTML elements like `<basefont>` and they gave the same result. Very strange. Then again, W3Schools messes up on a lot of things, so there. I'm not sure about PHP's XSLT implementation though.

Comment: @BoltClock - Bingo! (and thanks) I tried your idea in my PHP code as well, and we may have identified a bug with PHP's XSLT implementation. When I rename the "area" element as "basefont", I get exactly the same problem. Odd.  Sadly, bugs.php.net is down right now.

Comment: Funnily this only affects certain HTML empty elements. Others like `<link>` seem to do just fine. Maybe it's because `<link>` is a non-empty element in the RSS/RDF/Atom spec.

Comment: `<xsl:output method="html"/>` - you asked for it, so it was delivered to you. Computers are only at your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct; the main cause of this is that you are using `xsl:output` with html method. With this, the processor is allowed to output non well formed documents. The `area` tag is an HTML tag without end tag as many others like `br` and so on. You can resolve your problem just be changing output method to XML.

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

You may experience the same behavior with any XSLT 1.0 compliant processor (like Saxon 6.5).

Comment: Thank, empo. That fixed it. My love/hate relationship with XSLT deepens.

Comment: No don't blame HTML, blame yourself. If you ask for HTML output format but want XML, you have only yourself to blame.

Answer (score 0):

This is the output I get on the w3schools demo:

```
<row>
    <subrecipientname>TESTING123</subrecipientname>
    <servicename>BEFORE</servicename>
    <area>BETWEEN</area>
    <typedesc>AFTER</typedesc>
</row>
```

One thing to note is that area is an html element and you may be encountering issues because of that.

Comment: W3Schools isn't related to W3C.

Comment: LOL, that's funny.  I didn't even realize I did that.